# QNetworkAccessManager Memory Leakage

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am having some trouble with memory leaks while using the QNetworkAccessManager (using Qt). The more requests I call, the more memory is allocated. This makes sense, but not to me with the way I do it. I call, let's say 16 requests, and then once the network reply is hit 16 times, I call the next 16. With this method, wouldn't this regulate memory fine? For some reason it is not, and the memory increases steadily as more are called. Could having this in a thread be affecting this?

Header:

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QSemaphore>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QDebug>

#include "winnames.h"

#define MAX_REQUEST_COUNT 16

class Downloader : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Downloader(QObject *parent = 0);
    void start(Priority = InheritPriority);

signals:
    void PictureDownloaded(QPixmap picture, QString id);

public slots:
    void networkReply(QNetworkReply*);

private:
    void startDownloads();

    QString titleID;
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;

    int amount;
};
```

CPP:

```
#include "downloader.h"

Downloader::Downloader(QObject *parent) : QThread(parent)
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(networkReply(QNetworkReply*)));
}
void Downloader::start(Priority p)
{
    amount = 0;
    titleID = "50";
    startDownloads();
}

void Downloader::startDownloads()
{
    const int searchValues[] = {0, 0x400, 0x1000, 0x8000, 0xFFFF};
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        int num = searchValues[x] + amount;
        if (num >= searchValues[x + 1])
            continue;

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_REQUEST_COUNT; i++)
            manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://my.url/" + titleID.toUpper() + "/someDir/" + QString("%1").arg(num + i, 4, 16, QChar('0')).toUpper())));
    }
}

void Downloader::networkReply(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if (reply->bytesAvailable() != 0)
    {
        QPixmap pixmap;
        pixmap.loadFromData(reply->readAll(), "PNG");
        if (!pixmap.isNull())
            emit PictureDownloaded(pixmap, titleID + reply->url().toString().mid(reply->url().toString().length() - 4));
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
    reply->close();

    QMutex m;
    m.lock();

    if (amount++ != 0 && amount % MAX_REQUEST_COUNT == 0)
        startDownloads();

    m.unlock();
}
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You are not actually starting the thread (As `start()` is not virtual, it shouldn't be overriden, the thread body should rather be in `run()`, the manager wasn't moved to the thread with `moveToThread()` so it still runs in the main thread and `QPixmap` can't be used in a thread at all as it is dependant of the GUI unlike `QImage`), but you probably don't need threads as since Qt 4.8, `QNetworkAccessManager` is already multithreaded on its own. But the number of simultaneous requests per manager is limited to 6. **The memory leak may depend on what you do in the slot receiving the image.**

Comment: I continuously get this error when calling manager->moveToThread(this); in the run() function of my thread.

"(Parent is QNetworkAccessManager(0x10103fb8), parent's thread is Downloader(0x100e0508), current thread is QThread(0x1b53120)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread."

I initialize the manager in the run() method also, with no parent passed in the constructor.

Comment: 1. [You don't need threads](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QNetworkAccessManager.html#details). 2. “[You're doing it wrong](http://qt-project.org/wiki/ThreadsEventsQObjects)”.

Comment: @hetelek did you solve your problem? I have almost the same problem as you.

Comment: @kalkin Yes, I ended up not threading it (using another class inheriting from QThread) and using the QNetworkAccessManager's signals and slots itself.